# Securely passing tokens between functions

Tags: javascript, security

I'm looking for a way that one piece of code (A) can generate some kind of token, and then pass it to some other piece of code (B) in such a way that a 3rd piece of code is unable to intercept it (E).

For the purposes of this question assume that A can generate the token securely.

If B exposes some function F to A which accepts, as one of it's arguments, an object which will contain the token, then A can pass that token directly.

But E can find this token by, for example, overwriting `console.log` and examining the stack.

```
var x = console.log
console.log = function Eve()
{
  x.apply(this, arguments);
  console.info(Thing.caller.arguments);
}
```

(assuming that F invokes `console.log` of course, but in reality there are plenty such functions that could be overwritten in this way)

I think I have a mitigation against this, which is to delete the secure token from the passed object before calling any potentially compromised functions.
i.e.

```
var y = function Y(Secure)
{
  var Thing = Secure.Arg;
  delete Secure.Arg;
  console.log('SomeMessage', arguments) ;
}
y({Arg:'SomeArg'})
```

(in FF at least) manipulating the object argument also changes its value on the stack so the `arguments` object on the stack now contains an empty object.
Are there any other means that E can gain access to the passed data?
If yes, can those methods be mitigated or should I look into other options with better security?

EDIT for Clarity: It is assumed that E is injected by means outside the control of A or B - e.g. greasemonkey user script

Comment: i think u will have a bad time preventing this other solutions would be: host the 3rd piece of code yourself. run it inside an iframe on a different origin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a run-once getter and closure to keep private data off the stack:

```
function A(secret){ 
   return function(){
      var s=secret; 
      secret=null; 
      return s;
   };  
}

function B(fn){ 
    var v=fn(); 
    console.log(fn); 
    alert("In B(): " + v);  
}

var x=A(123); //give secret number to A, getting back a function
alert(x); // no secret here

B(x); // extract the secret by executing a one-time getter
alert(x);  // no secret here

alert(x()); // still no secret, it's used-up
```

since JS uses reference-based security, removing the ref provides security.

Also note that you can set breakpoints to get arguments values, but you can't use try/catch, console.log() or any other user-land trick to recover the 123 in-between A and B in the code above.

You have to run the function to get the value, and running the function destroys the value.

the problem with object properties as OP's code uses is that the secret value is visible on the object if an exception happens, whereas a closure would keep its secret.

Comment: up voted this creative solution. Though might one still hook into function B to intercept  the token?

Comment: @Roberto: i don't see how, but you can make the dumb getter smarter. in non-strict, there's even the cool trick of `function tell(){alert(Function.prototype.toString.call(arguments.callee.caller));} function coolName(){ tell(); } coolName();` so that tell() can tell exactly what is calling it, validating the code if needed. maybe MD5?

Comment: The malicious code could define function B before you and also can overwrite `Function.prototype.toString = () => 'asd';`

Comment: @RolandStarke: well yeah, if they replace `B` all bets are off, this is within the locus of control raised by OP. aside: running `delete Function.prototype.toString` first will allow the `callee.caller` code to un-obscure , and i don't think there's a way around that yet ;)

Comment: I've not tried it yet but I like the idea of this solution.
Currently I'm having trouble making sure other aspects are secure also (where the token came from & where it goes next), so this may become moot.

Comment: Ended up taking a different approach due to unresolvable issues elsewhere in the flow. So I'm accepting this answer even though I've not tried it myself

Answer (score 1):

It's already a disater if you use a third party library that might overwrite your own code for bad purposes. So the best solution is to use another trustworthy one.

If you're still interested in protecting the token from those libraries, you can define *unwritable* functions with `Object.defineProperty`.

```
var obj = {};
Object.defineProperty(obj,'unwritableMethod',{
    value: function(token){
        //do stuff with this token
    },
    writable: false
});
var x = obj.unwritableMethod;
var maliciousMethod = function Eve()
{
  x.apply(this, arguments);
  console.info(Thing.caller.arguments);
};
// This will be silently ignored.
obj.unwritableMethod = maliciousMethod;
//you can test the result with this
console.log(obj.unwritableMethod === maliciousMethod); //false
```